# How to sort numpy arrays of a list based on the averages of columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a list of numpy arrays and want to firstly sort each array and then sort whole the array in my list. The first step is clear for me. It is my data:

```
unsorted=[np.array([[2.5, 6., 5.1],\
                    [3.5, 7., 0.1],\
                    [2.5, 7., 0.],\
                    [3.5, 6., 0.1]]),\
          np.array([[2.5, 6., 1.],\
                    [1.5, 7., 5.2]]),\
          np.array([[1.5, 7., 0.2],\
                    [2.5, 7., 1.2]])]
```

Firstly I sort each array based on first and second column using the following code:

```
sorted_arr=[]    
for i in unsorted:
    i=i[np.lexsort((i[:,0],i[:,1]))]
    sorted_arr.append(i)
```

Then, I want to also sort my arrays in the list. I want to sort them based on the average of first and second column. For first array averages of first and second column are: `3.` and `6.5`. For second array it is `2.` and `6.5`. For last array are `2.` and `7`. I want to sort array firstly based on the average of second column and then first column. I mean I want my final result to be:

```
sorted_arr=[array([[2.5, 6. , 1. ],
                   [1.5, 7. , 5.2]]),
            array([[1.5, 7. , 0.2],
                   [2.5, 7. , 1.2]]),
            array([[2.5, 6. , 5.1],
                   [3.5, 6. , 0.1],
                   [2.5, 7. , 0. ],
                   [3.5, 7. , 0.1]])]
```

I do appreciate any help to do so in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `sorted_arr`, you can do:

```
sorted(sorted_arr, key=lambda x: tuple(x[:,:2].mean(0)))
```

Comment: Doesn't that sort on the average of the first column first and then on the average of the second column?

Comment: @BioGeek yes indeed, but it matches OP’s expected output. If it goes other way, it wouldn’t match the output. I think OP needs to clarify here.